# python-Get a string after specific word in line

Tags: python, json, string

I'm searching JIRA tickets which have specific subject.I put results in JSON file (whole file:https://1drv.ms/f/s!AizscpxS0QM4attoSBbMLkmKp1s)

I wrote a python code to get ticket description

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import json

if sys.version[0] == '2':

    reload(sys)

    sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8")

sys.stdout = open('output.txt','wt')
datapath = sys.argv[1]
data = json.load(open(datapath))
for issue in data['issues']:
  if len(issue['fields']['subtasks']) == 0 or 'description' in issue['fields']:
   custom_field = issue['fields']['description']
   my_string=custom_field
   #print custom_field
   print my_string.split("name:",1)[1]
```

Some tickets have this value in description:

```
 "description": "name:some name\r\n\r\ncount:5\r\n\r\nregion:some region\r\n\r\n\u00a0",
```

i need to get values after Name, count and region for all tickets:

desired output (in this example JSON file):

```
some name 5  some region
some name 5  some region
```

With code above i can get all values after name

```
some name^M
^M
count:5^M
^M
region:some region
```

Also, how to skip processing tickets which have no these values in description, in that case i get:

```
 print custom_field.split("name",1)[2]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a job for a regular expression:

```
>>> import re
>>> x = r"(\w+):(.+)\r\n\r"
>>> regexp = re.compile(x)
>>> s = "name:some name\r\n\r\ncount:5\r\n\r\nregion:some region\r\n\r\n\u00a0"
>>> regexp.findall(s)
[('name', 'some name'), ('count', '5'), ('region', 'some region')]
```

Or, if you want a dictionary back,

```
>>> dict(regexp.findall(s))
{'count': '5', 'region': 'some region', 'name': 'some name'}
```

You can drop the keys from the dict like this:

```
>>> mydict = dict(regexp.findall(s))
>>> mydict.values()
mydict.values()
['5', 'some region', 'some name']
```

But be careful, because they may not be in the order you expect. To match your desired output:

```
>>> mydict = dict(regexp.findall(s))
>>> print("{name} {count:2s} {region}".format(**mydict))
some name 5  some region
```

If you don't have the expected values, the `findall()` call will return an empty or incomplete list. In that case you must check the returned dict before printing it, otherwise the `format()` call will fail.

One way to ensure that the dict always has the expected values is to set it up beforehand with defaults.

```
>>> mydict = {'count': 'n/a', 'region': 'n/a', 'name': 'n/a'}
>>> mydict.update(dict(regexp.findall(s)))
```

Then the `format()` call will always work, even if one of the fields is missing from the data.

Comment: It works !!, thanks, how to get only values (5,some region,some name)) ?

Comment: didn't see you complete post, it works for one description filed, but if JSON file has more descriptions (more tickets) then it prints only first line   `print("{name} {count:2s} {region}".format(**mydict))
KeyError: 'region'`

Comment: @Milister I did make the point that you have to check the dict before formatting it because it might be incomplete. But I've updated the answer to provide one way to deal with that. There are others, for example `if region in mydict:`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this try catch expression

```
try:
        print custom_field.split("name",1)[2]
except :
        print("Skipping ..")
```